# Change the color of a cell based on another cells color in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am New to Sheets. I need to change the color of D1 cell to color of the F3 cell. If I change the color of F3 cell the changes should also be seen in D1 cell.

[image: Reference of the sheet]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider using the same [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule with all cells whose color you want to control the same way. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Not possible without script.